# HTTP ERROR 404 Jenkins serves only static files on this domain

Tags: jenkins

I am getting "HTTP ERROR 404 Jenkins serves only static files on this domain" when ever i am accessing the Jenkins page. I think i tried to edit the URL of Jenkins page then after i have got this error. I have deleted and install Jenkins again using Brew command. I also have upgraded the Jenkins to 2.236 version, but still no luck. i downloaded this Jenkins form Jenkins page not using Docker. I already had googled it and find nothing. would someone help me out.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4U6si.png

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue when I edited the Resource URL field to be "http://localhost:8080/"

It can be accessed by travelling through the below actions

> Manage Jenkins >> Configure System >> Resource root URL

[image]

And that was when I started encountering the above-mentioned issue. Because this is not allowing me to open the Jenkins on the 8080 port, I opened Jenkins using the below command in another port using the below command:

```
java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=8081
```

This opened Jenkins in another port and I deleted the Resource URL field entry which then allowed me to access Jenkins on the 8080 port.

Answer (score 0):

1. Using the CLI, navigate to where your `$JENKINS_HOME` directory is, and open the file `./jenkins.security.ResourceDomainConfiguration.xml` using a text editor.

   ```bash
   vi $JENKINS_HOME/jenkins.security.ResourceDomainConfiguration.xml
   ```
2. Edit the contents of `./jenkins.security.ResourceDomainConfiguration.xml`. Remove the URL you had previously set which caused the HTTP 404 error.

   ```
     <?xml version='1.1' encoding='UTF-8'?>
     <jenkins.security.ResourceDomainConfiguration>
   -     <url>https://old-url.com/jenkins/</url>
   +     <url></url>
     </jenkins.security.ResourceDomainConfiguration>
   ```
3. Save file changes, and then restart the Jenkins server.

   ```bash
   systemctl restart jenkins #you might need sudo
   ```

This was tested on the following Jenkins versions:

- v2.375.1
- v2.263.4